# Which gems can be skipped while still achieving "The Ultimate Gem Path"?

Tags: achievements, crash-bandicoot-n-sane-trilogy

I'm currently completing a walkthrough guide for the achievements in *"Crash Bandicoot N. Sane Trilogy"*. In *"Crash Bandicoot"*, you need a total of 26 gems to be able to unlock all of the achievements. However, there are a total of 27 gems, including the gem in *"Stormy Ascent"*. I started wondering what was the best gem to skip, if aiming for completing the achievement set as efficiently as possible.

*"Castle Machinery"* appears to be the winner; there is a shortcut that bypasses all of the boxes. However, the level isn't all that hard to complete with the clear gem.

It would be ideal to skip a coloured gem; those levels all require completing the level without reloading from a checkpoint. Depending on player skill, these gems could take considerably more time to unlock.

I have seen some speedrunning techniques where players were able to use exploits to enter coloured gem paths *before* unlocking the respective coloured gem. If I can do this with *all* paths of a particular colour, I'd effectively be able to ignore that coloured gem.

I've watched a few speedruns, and spent hours researching on speedrun.com; but I'm not sure if there are any other skips I may have missed. In *"Crash Bandicoot*", which coloured gem paths can be completed prior to unlocking the respective coloured gems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based off the other posted answer, I was able to complete enough research to reach a satisfactory conclusion. Only two coloured gem path skips remain, making it impossible to completely skip any single coloured gem in order to unlock the *"C1 | The Ultimate Gem Path"* achievement. The most efficient gem to skip remains the clear gem in *"Castle Machinery"*, by taking the green gem path to skip most of the level.

---

Both skips are used in [the current speedrun.com record](https://www.speedrun.com/crashnst/run/yv2vpexm) for [*"Crash Bandicoot N. Sane Trilogy - Crash Bandicoot One - All Gems"*](https://www.speedrun.com/crashnst/full_game#Crash_Bandicoot).

### The Great Gate

*"The Great Gate"* normally requires the yellow gem from *"The Lab"* in order to collect the clear gem. However, it is possible to stand on the edge of the exit warp and jump across to the other side, bypassing the requirement for using the yellow gem platform.

### Cortex Power

*"Cortex Power*" normally requires the blue gem from *"Toxic Waste"* in order to collect the clear gem. However, it is possible to make it across the toxic waste without using the blue gem platform by jumping up on one of the zappers earlier along the left side path. An Aku Aku mask is required for this skip, to avoid immediately dying from touching the zapper.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen of the N Sane trilogy, I don't believe a lot of the original skip strategies still work. In addition to this, I don't think there are any gem trails that can be accessed without the gem, or at least not without great difficulty (though I can't really be certain), which is why I haven't seen any strats of this in speedrunning.

There are some ways to get the *gems* early/faster (depending on the level): for example [Getting the Yellow Gem Early in CB3](https://www.speedrun.com/crash3/guide/9b8ye).

Speedrun.com would likely be the primary resource to find any of these strats, and you can compare the old strats with the new, then potentially go from there.

- [Crash Bandicoot N-Sane Trilogy Guides](https://www.speedrun.com/crashnst/guides)
- [Crash Bandicoot 1 Guides](https://www.speedrun.com/crash1/guides)
- [Crash Bandicoot 2 Guides](https://www.speedrun.com/crash2/guides)
- [Crash Bandicoot 3 Guides](https://www.speedrun.com/crash3/guides)